# Task<T> async causing Xamarin.iPhone (MonoTouch) JIT error?

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, servicestack, xamarin, jit

I use the ServiceStack dll’s quite a bit but they had not exposed appropriate async methods so I went ahead and made these myself.

Please can someone assist me with the issue I have come across as it’s prohibiting me from running code on the iPhone?

The code works beautifully on WP8 and Android however it breaks horribly on iPhone due to JIT limitations. The error I receive is the following:
*Attempting to JIT compile method 'ServiceStack.ServiceClient.Web.AsyncServiceClient:SendAsync (string,string,object)' while running with --aot-only. See http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/about/limitations for more information.*

I have tried in Debug mode, Release mode and with all of the available linker options to no avail. The problem definitely lies with how I have implemented the new async calls in the AsyncServiceClient.cs file. For the changes made to ServiceStack codem, please see my Github repo [here](https://github.com/dylanvdmerwe/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Common/ServiceClient.Web/AsyncServiceClient.cs).

Example Android and iPhone projects can be found [here](http://d-h.st/y0h). One is for Android which works flawlessly and the other is for iPhone. Would it be possible for someone to assist me with what I need to change in order to get this code to work on the iPhone runtime? I am not sure if there is a bug or if there is something I would be required to change?

Xamarin.iPhone 6.4 and Xamarin.Android 4.8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be an issue with Mono runtime. Logged [here](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=13669) and is reported as being fixed in upcoming versions.